# how check two user defined objects in java

Tags: java, string

I have one class and I want compare two objects of that class. Is there any method to 
compare two user defined objects. I don't want to do it manually.

```
public class NewClass {

    private String name;
    private String surnamename;
    private String address;

    public NewClass(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public NewClass(String name, String surname, String address)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.surnamename = surname;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurnamename() {
        return surnamename;
    }
    public void setSurnamename(String surnamename) {
        this.surnamename = surnamename;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

I want to compare two objects of this class. how could I accomplish this?

```
NewClass newClass1 = new NewClass("kshitij", "solanki", "nadiad");      
NewClass newClass2 = new NewClass("kshitij", "solanki", "nadiad");

    String s1 = new String("kshitij");
    String s2 = new String("kshitij");

    NewClass s3 = new NewClass("kshitij");
    NewClass s4 = new NewClass("kshitij");

    System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(s2.hashCode());

    System.out.println(s3.hashCode());
    System.out.println(s4.hashCode());

    System.out.println(newClass1 == newClass2);
    System.out.println(newClass1.toString() == newClass2.toString());
    System.out.println(newClass1.toString().equals(newClass2.toString()));
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html

Comment: Are you trying to check the equality (result is either true or false) of two objects or do a comparison (result is either -1, or 0, or 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to implement `equals` and `hashCode`, e.g.

```
public boolean equals(final Object other) {
  if (other instanceof NewClass) {
    final NewClass _other = (NewClass) other;
    return name.equals(_other.name)
      && (surname == null && surname == _other.surname
        || surname.equals(_other.surname))
      && (address == null && address == _other.address
        || address.equals(_other.address));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

public int hashCode() {
  return name.hashCode() * 961
    + (surname == null ? 0 : surname.hashCode()) * 31
    + (address == null ? 0 : address.hashCode());
}
```

Now, you can compare `NewClass` instances by their *semantics*, e.g.

```
/* they are equal */
assert new NewClass("A", "B", "C").equals(new NewClass("A", "B", "C"));
```

Answer (score 1):

That is what `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods are for.

Override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in `NewClass`

Inside `equals()` method code your equality condition and use same variables for [hashcode()](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20) calculation also.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `equals()` method.

the method is available in `java.lang.Object`

this method is basically used to compare two objects.

this method can be overriden for the special purpose.

and the method basically returns `boolean` value.